# Trouble establishing connection to Local SQL database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, sqlconnection

Simply trying to find out the correct syntax for my connection string. Before anyone asks, yes I did look at other SO answers, and no they did not work for me. Here a couple of attempts I made from looking at other SO questions like the one I am asking

```
Server=(local);Database=SalesOrdersExample;Integrated Security= true
Data Source=(local);Database=SalesOrdersExample;Integrated Security=SSPI
Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SalesOrdersExampleDataSet;Integrated Security=true
```

None of them worked (I have a `Console.WriteLine("test");` thrown in there and it works up until I try `conn.Open()` (opening the connection to database) so I'm assuming that it must be my connection string since nothing gets written after `conn.Open()`)

```
Console.WriteLine("test"); // works

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SalesOrdersExampleDataSet;Integrated Security=true");

Console.WriteLine("test"); // works         
conn.Open();

Console.WriteLine("test"); // does not work
```

So some information about the database is that it's local under my 'Data Connections' in my Server Explorer. I also have the .xsd file in my project so I have linked the Data Set to the current project I am on. Here is a picture representation to confirm that I have both the Data Connection and the Data Set.

EDIT: SO does not allow me to post pictures until I have 10 rep so here is direct link to picture:

[DB Screenshot](http://www.jdmdev.net/DB_Pic.png)

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your application to see what, if any, errors are thrown during execution?

Comment: I have not not sure how to do that in C# but I am assuming it's a connection error because when I throw Console.WriteLine("test"); it works up until I open the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio comes with LocalDB database, which is not exactly SQL Server Express database.

Try something like this:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
```

or

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0; AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf; InitialCatalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

If using in c# code, you can use @ to avoid problems with backslash characters:

```
SqlConnection conn = 
   new SqlConnection(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;");
```

Comment: `LocalDB` ***IS*** exactly SQL Server Express - just in another form (in an "on-demand loaded" form, instead of running as a server - but it's ***exactly*** the same code base) .....

Comment: yeah i actually found out my connectionstring was messed up which is why it wasn't working. i used your advice with the @("") so I upchecked you.